# Jquery open links in current static tab instead of leaving the page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to open links in the current tab instead of leaving the page and I found this [example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#...open_links_in_the_current_tab_instead_of_leaving_the_page) but only works if tabs are loaded via Ajax

How can I make it work with static tabs?

> ```
> $('#example').tabs({
> load: function(event, ui) {
>     $('a', ui.panel).click(function() {
>         $(ui.panel).load(this.href);
>         return false;
>     });
> } });
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You need to invoke this script on your `div` where your static content placed (try after `.tabs()` initializing):

```
$('.tab').each(function() {
   var tab = $(this);
   tab.find('a').click(function() {
       tab.load(this.href);
       return false;
   });
});
```

or try the handle on `create` event:

```
$("#example").tabs({
   create: function(event, ui) { 
               $('a', ui.panel).click(function() {
                  $(ui.panel).load(this.href);
                  return false;
               });
           }
});
```